# How can I activate my Apple Remote?

Tags: hardware, remote, apple

I have a A1294 Apple Remote  model no 2B9450C4RBRCA that I cannot configure for my Ubuntu desktop. I have built all the dependencies for lirc, but it still doesn't show up.

I'm running Ubuntu on a Desktop and not a Mac.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I overlooked that Apple remote only works with built-in infrared as explained [here on Apple support](http://support.apple.com/en-za/HT201584). Since my PC doesn't have that feature there's no solution.